# Pure CSS: Select elements that have n or more siblings

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select some elements on the basis that there are **more than a number of siblings**, like:

- In tables, when there are more than a given number of rows (e.g. there are equal or more than 3 sibling `<tr>` elements) I want to select all rows (not the table)
- Lists that have more than a given number of items (e.g. there are equal or more than 3 sibling `<li>` elements) I want to select all items (not the list)

I know that there is `:not(:only-child)` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624032/79485) but I would like something like

```
tr:min-siblings(3) {
    color: blue;
}
```

**Can I use the count of siblings as a selector of all those siblings?**

*Note: I am looking for a CSS only solution this time.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible by a technique, which is described well at Lea Verou's Blog CSS Secrets: [Styling Elements based on sibling count](https://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/).

It's based on the follwing observation:
**If you know that the first element is also the third last element, you also know that there are three siblings altogether.**

All you have to do now is to select this first and 3rd last element plus all its following siblings.

```
tbody > tr:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
tbody > tr:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ tr {}
```

I enhanced this a little bit, to be more dynamic and made a SCSS mixin in this codepen

The mixin is as follows:

```
// SCSS
@mixin yuboo-childcount($count, $element, $element-selective: null, $rest: false) {
  $el: $element;
  $els: $element;
  @if $element-selective {
    $els: $element-selective;
  }
  $co: $count;
  @if $rest {
    $co: n + #{$count};
  }

  @if $count == 1 {
    & > #{$els}:first-child:nth-last-of-type(#{$co}) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    & > #{$els}:first-child:nth-last-of-type(#{$co}),
    & > #{$el}:first-child:nth-last-of-type(#{$co}) ~ #{$els} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

If I include it like this:

```
tbody {
  @include yuboo-childcount('3', tr) {
    /* my rules */
  }
}
```

it yields:

```
tbody > tr:first-child:nth-last-of-type(3), 
tbody > tr:first-child:nth-last-of-type(3) ~ tr {
  /* my rules */
}
```

Your example

> ```
> tr:min-siblings(3) {
>     color: blue;
> }
> ```

which I interpret as saying: `color` should be set to `blue` for every `tr` inside a `tbody`, when there are 3 or more `tr`s in that `tbody`, would be solved as follows:

```
tbody {
  @include yuboo-childcount('n+3', tr) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

becoming this CSS

```
tbody > tr:first-child:nth-last-of-type(n+3), 
tbody > tr:first-child:nth-last-of-type(n+3) ~ tr {
  color: blue;
}
```

Check this example

```css
tr {
  color: red;
  background-color: pink;
}
tbody > tr:first-child:nth-last-of-type(n+3), 
tbody > tr:first-child:nth-last-of-type(n+3) ~ tr {
  color: blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

td {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid gold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I stand corrected! This answer is such a clever solution.

Comment: @NathanDawson You shouldn't have deleted your answer. It's technically correct while not be applicable at the moment. But it might be worth in the future.

Comment: Cool. It works very well! However, the `first-element` part seems unnecessary. I managed to do it without. I now have `tbody > tr:nth-last-of-type(n+3), 
tbody > tr:nth-last-of-type(n+3) ~ tr`

Comment: @Marcel I don't think, it's unnecessary. Or your original problem was a different then I assumed,

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
tr::nth-child(1n+4){
 // your awesome styles
}
```

[Here's a codepen with a working example](https://codepen.io/itamarok/pen/eYOGYod)

This tells the selector to find each 1st child (skip nothing) - and offset 4 to start with - which puts you at your 3rd element :-)

Comment: The op wants to select the table, not the row.

Comment: @Esko No, no, I want to select the rows (all rows), not the table. However, in practice this would have a very similar outcome. I'll clarify the question though.

Comment: @Marcel Well it depends on what is the context, but basically you do want to select the parent that has certain amount of children. Be it the table with rows or the row with cells :)

Comment: @Esko No, as per the (existing) title, I want to select all siblings, if there are more than n. To me, in practice, this makes a difference to selecting the parent.

Comment: @Marcel That's what my answer sought to address. There is no CSS-only solution yet. I explained how it would work once it is available but I wouldn't count on it arriving any time soon :) For now you'll have to take a different approach.

Comment: Oh okay @Marcel - so does my solution help?

Comment: @itamar If you want to select the children, it's totally possible. See my answer.

Comment: @yunzen I don't think I said you couldn't.